# Use Categories Path for Product URLs NO not working for one store of multi-store setup

Tags: magento-1.7, url-rewrite, product-urls

I have 2 stores on a my Magento setup ver. 1.7.0.2

`http://www.gmesupply.com` and `http://www.colsafety.com`

I am trying to use the option "Use Categories Path for Product URL" NO for both store but the rewrites are not being created correctly for one of the stores.

Colsafety.com creates rewrites for all of the product pages. Gmesupply.com only creates rewrites for URLs containing categories.

For example...
Colsafety rewrite:

```
67600-elkriver-peregrine-platinum-harness --> catalog/product/view/id/3718
```

Gmesupply rewrite:

```
safety-equipment/harnesses/elkriver-67600-peregrine-platinum-harness --> catalog/product/view/id/3718/category/12368
```

Both stores use the exact same product database so I'm not sure why it's working for one and not the other. I have made sure setting are correct under both store views. I have tried emptying the `core_url_rewrite` tables, reindexed, and cleared the cache.

Any ideas on why it isn't working on GME Supply?

Answer (score 1):

Setting `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` to `No` will have no effect on the contents of the `core_url_rewrite` table. Magento will always generate all possible URL combinations, no matter what the settings are. From what I can tell, this setting is only forcing Magento to return direct product URL when `getProductUrl` method is called on a product model instance.

You can check by executing following query:

```
SELECT * FROM core_url_rewrite WHERE product_id = 3718;
```

This should produce multiple results depending on how many stores and categories are involved.

Comment: Here's what I got http://www.gmesupply.com/images/screenshot-table.JPG

Comment: Can you recommend where to edit gmesupply.com so that it pulls the direct product URL?

Comment: It's really hard to tell as this should work out of the box. Which page is in question?

Comment: It isn't working for any products on gmesupply.com at all. It won't automatically create redirects for direct product URLS. It will only create them for Columbia Safety.